# Uploading array of Files to server using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

The Apis for the application has been already developed. The api works on POSTMAN.
[POSTMAN Request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT9HT.png)
I can't figure out how to do the same in android using retrofit. I have tried array list. Each time i get the same errorMsg. 
 `{"error":true,"errorMsg":"The images must be an array."}`
**The APi works fine in postman.**

My code is

My Interface

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload/prescription")
fun uploadPrescription(
    @Query("token") token: String,
    @Part image: List<MultipartBody.Part>): Call<RequestBody>
```

My code to call to server

```
 val file = File(imageUri.toString())
 val requestBody:RequestBody = RequestBody.create("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull(),file)

 val multiType = ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part>()

 multiType.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("images","123456",requestBody))

 val call = RetrofitClient.getApiWithGson().uploadPrescription(SharedPref.getIsToken(this@AttachPrescription).toString(),multiType)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<RequestBody> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<RequestBody>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("Failure",t.message.toString())
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<RequestBody>, response: Response<RequestBody>) {
            Log.d("Response Upload",response.body().toString())
        }

    })
```

And I got output

```
Response Upload: {"error":true,"errorMsg":"The images must be an array."}
```

Please try to help me it would be very helpful
Thanks

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: try changing `List<MultipartBody.Part>` to a `MultipartBody.Part` `Array`, If that doesn't help contact your backend team

Comment: Array<MultipartBody.Part> I also use this but still showing same

Comment: This response you are getting is sent to you from Backend, check with them what they want as request data and if needed ask then to echo the response so that error can be found

Comment: The backend developer said me that he want "array of Files" And I also check it in postman which is working fine so that is why I'm confused @RakshitNawani

Comment: The backend developer said me that he want "array of Files" And I also check it in postman which is working fine so that is why I'm confused @m3g4tr0n

Answer (score 0):

To send an array to backend is still the same as the code you have currently with just a little change:

```
multiType.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("images[]", fileName, requestBody))
```

You should note now that all the files is now using the same name followed by [].